# Loop through a datatable, get value and Header

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datatable

I have a `grid` that's populated from a `datatable`.

[image: Grid]

What I'm trying to achieve is to loop through each `row` & `column` that's **selected**, and store the set of values on variables so that I can update a table.

So for example, the loop should start with **P1**, store the value of 431/, P1 and 88.2 to three variables:

```
string sub = '431/'  
string code = 'P1'
decimal newbaseprice = 88.2
```

Perform an update:

```
UPDATE MyPriceTable
SET BasePrice = newbaseprice
WHERE PartNum = sub and ListCode=code
```

And so on until P2 & P3 are updated.

So far, I've been able to fetch the values from a specific row, but I can't figure how to get the column name and apply it to my update.

```
foreach(DataRow row in ((DataTable)this.grdPart.DataSource).Select("Seleccionar= true"))
        {
            string sub = row["SUB"].ToString();
            string p1 = row["P1"].ToString();
            string p2 = row["P2"].ToString();
            string p3 = row["P3"].ToString();
}
```

Does someone have another approach on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're DataBound on the Grid and wondering how to update the data behind the grid, then refresh your grid.

Your first problem is that more than one selection will lead you to overwriting in your loop.  That's going to make all values equivalent to the most recent iteration, which isn't helpful.  I recommend making a private nested class to deal with this.

```
private class DItem
{
   public string sub {get;set;}
   public string p1 {get;set;} 
   public string p2 {get;set;}
   public string p3 {get;set;}
}
```

And then you use it this way:

```
var litms = new List<DItem>()
foreach(DataRow row in ((DataTable)this.grdPart.DataSource).Select("Seleccionar= true"))
        {
            var item = new DItem();
            item.sub = row["SUB"].ToString();
            item.p1 = row["P1"].ToString();
            item.p2 = row["P2"].ToString();
            item.p3 = row["P3"].ToString();
            litms.Add(item);
        }
```

Then you can just call your list of your class using Linq and assign the values that way, or (the right way) update your `DataTable` with the values and re-bind. You can use the column names, or their indeces so as to make the names irrelevant.